# Ramda.js how to pluck with digging object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I want to make an array which have items of id.

Here is my code.

```js
const list = [
  {
    meta: {
      id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    meta: {
      id: 1
    }
  }
]
    
const result = R.pluck('id')(R.pluck('meta')(list)) // → [0, 1]
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

I am doing pluck twice and I think this is not cool.

Any coolest way to do this?

I want to use Ramda.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word around town is that this is pretty cool:

```js
const list = [
  {
    meta: {
      id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    meta: {
      id: 1
    }
  }
]

const result = R.map(R.path(['meta', 'id']))(list);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are great! Thaknyou! I didn't know R.path!